# PCA in R long form

Tags: r, reshape, pca, melt, princomp

I would like to do PCA on a dataframe that is in long form:

> time1 id1 data11
>
> time1 id2 data12
>
> time2 id1 data21
>
> etc.

Is there an easy way to do this or is the standard way to `reshape` it and then do `princomp`.  My dataset is pretty large with roughly 40,000 times and 4,000 ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such a simple reshaping I think all you need is

```
m <- matrix(mydata[,3],nrow=ntimes,byrow=TRUE)
princomp(m)
```

This should give you a `ntimes` by `nIDs` matrix to play with.  It will be (potentially a lot) faster than `reshape`.

Comment: great suggestion - thank you! i'll give that a shot but seems like it will work.

Comment: Faster, but also more dangerous.

Comment: Fair enough. The resulting matrix will be 610 Mb, though (`print(object.size(seq(1.6e8)),units="Mb")` [or I could just have multiplied 4 bytes by 1.6e8!] The OP might need all the speed they can get.  I was going to run some benchmarks but I can't easily create such a big object on my laptop.